# Postgres schemas with Pony ORM

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, ponyorm

How can I select which postgres schema to use in PonyORM?

I've tried to login with a role that has permission to only one schema called "test1", but it connects me to the public schema. So, i deleted the public schema an then it gave me an error:

```
 ProgrammingError: no schema has been selected to create in
 LINE 1: CREATE TABLE "customers" (
```

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106057/error-no-schema-has-been-selected-to-create-in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in two possible ways.

First is specify your connection

```
db = Database()
... # models definition
pg = dict(
    provider='postgres', 
    user='username', 
    password='pwd', 
    host='localhost', 
    database='db', 
    options='-c search-path=SCHEMA NAME') # here you specify default schema
db.bind(**pg)
db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)
```

Second is specify `_table_` option for entity

```
class Person(db.Entity):
    _table_ = ('schemaname', 'tablename')
    attribute = ...
```